# How do I define HSV ranges for following colors more accurately?

Tags: python, opencv, colors, hsv

I have defined the HSV color space to classify objects color in a real-world problem. 
Since my problem is a real word problem like classifying car color, I'd like to define more colors. However, I figured out my HSV color classification is making mistakes for some colors like white, brown, gray and some other colors.

Here are the HSV color values that I defined in my program. I would like to get the most accurate result, I was wondering if you could please review and edit the ranges?

Comment: Ranges for colors will depend upon your image and the exact hues, saturation and values there. The best way, is to measure those values in your actual HSV image and give them some extra range. White (or any shade of gray) has no saturation and its hue is the same as red. Brown is often hard to do. I am not sure why you have trouble with blue. Perhaps your hue needs a wider range or your saturation low value needs to be lower. HSV in OpenCV has hue range of 0 to 180.

Comment: some dark brown and black color objects are classified as blue.

Comment: Black (white and any shade of gray) has H=0,S=0. They only vary in V. So set you low and high H and S values for any gray shade near zero. Your brown is too wide. Take your brown RGB color and enter it in some online RGB->HSV converter. Get the HSV values in the range (0-360,0-255,0-255) and divide the H by 2. Then make a reasonable range about those values